# Batch file authentication fail when connecting to linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I have a stored procedure which takes data from a linked server and inserts it into a table on my own server. This works fine if I run the Sproc manually within SQL, but when I try and run the sproc via a batch file, I get an authentication failure. It seems the batch needs to have connection information to be able to run the sproc successfully.

I am using osql with the following commands -S -d -Q -U -P

Is this correct? It seems I need to be able to define two databases (mine and the one from the linked server).

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Who is complaining? osql, sql local server, sql remote server ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try -E (trusted connection) instead of -U -P. this uses windows authentication instead of sql authentication

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it to work. Issue was I was using the credentials for getting onto the Linked Server. I needed to use the credentials for my own server (probably obvious to most :P).